# How does the RANDAO mechanism prevent DoS attacks in the beacon chain?

Tags: proof-of-stake, blocks, slots, slashings, beacon

I was reading through an explainer on the Beacon Chain at [ethos.dev](https://ethos.dev/beacon-chain), which mentioned that block proposers are selected via the RANDAO mechanism. This raised a question about the network's resilience to potential DoS attacks. If the network preselects the next proposer, does this mean all other proposals are ignored? Furthermore, is it possible for all validators to propose multiple blocks simultaneously, potentially leading to a DoS attack on the network? How does the RANDAO selection mechanism safeguard against such scenarios?